# Why aren't these regexes working as expected?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

When I run these commands, I get output like this:

[image: Screenshot of Terminal]

Here are the commands and output, in textual form:

```
$ cat exte
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii
```

This works fine:

```
$ egrep --color i\{4,5\} exte
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii
```

I guess it should show color only one or two "i" of a line, but the output colors everything:

```
$ egrep --color i\{1,2\} exte

i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii
```

Similarly, I can't see the extended regex working here:

```
$ egrep --color i? exte
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii


$ egrep --color i+ exte
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii
```

Comment: Use word boundaries.

Comment: Jup, with the i{1,2} you get multiple matches for the same line. So either use a word boundary, or use ^i{1,2}$ so it considers also the start and end of the line.

Comment: and for the last two examples with i+ and i?, the lines contain several i's each single one matching (none-or-more)(?) or (one-or-more)(+) so everything is correct, explain what/why exactly you expect

Comment: By default grep prints the **line** that matches a regexp so it's behaving exactly as designed. You might want the behavior you'd get with the `-o` option to print the **string** that matches the regexp instead of the **line** that contains the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

This command colors all, because in your file have that many i's.

```
$ egrep --color i\{1,2\} exte
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
iiiiii
```

Take the example of third line in output. You didn't specified any constraint for a line matching starting of the line or ending of the line. So, it matches one by one. So, the first two i's in the second third line is matched. For the third i it checks the condition, that time also the condition is true. So, it matches all.

If you want more clear output you can use the -o option to what are all matching.

-o:-

Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

```
$ egrep --color i? exte
```

The ? mark in grep regular expression, it matches zero or one occurrence of the preceding character. So, It is also working like the above command. All the i's matching one by one for the regex.

```
$ egrep --color i+ exte
```

The + means match one or more occurrence of the preceding character.
 So, it matches all the i's for line by line for a single occurrence.

If you want to see the output as clear format you have to use the -o option.